# How does RSS reader know that a feed is updated?

Tags: rss, push

Just learning about this via youtube but could not find answer to my question of how reader knows there is an update.

Is it like a Push in blackberry?

Answer (score 44):

RSS is a file format [source](http://www.whatisrss.com/) and doesn't actually *know* anything about where it gets the entries from. The answer really is: "how can an http request get only the newest results from a server" and the answer is **Conditional GET** [source](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3). Http also supports **Conditional PUT**.

[This is an article](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2002/10/21/http_conditional_get_for_rss_hackers/) about using this feature of http to specifically support rss hackers.

Comment: Awesome.  That article let me to the RSS terminology that I was looking for: "Conditional GET".  And that term lead me to find what I was looking for in the Python docs for feedparser.  Thanks again!  Everybody should +1 this answer!

Comment: Glad I could help, please accept the answer if it satisfied the learning required. Also please suggest edits if you feel more of the needed details should be included here.

Answer (score 20):

RSS is a pull technology. The reader re-fetches the RSS feed now and then (for example two times per hour, or more often if the reader learns that it's an often updated feed).

The feed is served through regular HTTP and consists of a simple XML file. It is always fetched from the same URL.

Comment: The question was how does the reader know that there's an update? Does it continuously read the same feeds? How does it know there's an update and not reload what already seen?

Comment: it does not know. the reader just check it constantly and compare to the cache (previous content, or previous timestamp) to figure out whether the rss feed is updated or not.

Answer (score 13):

It just check the feed for update regularly.

Recently there is a new protocol called [pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) to make feed push to the listener. But it requires the publishers support it.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/Companies) is a list of web services support real-time RSS pushing, including Google Reader, Blogger, FeedBurner, FriendFeed, MySpace, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Let's summarize :

- Usually, a client knows  that an RSS feed has been updated through polling, that is regular pull (HTTP GET request on the feed URL)
- Push doesn't exist on the web, at least, not with HTTP until [HTML5 websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is fixed.
- However, some blog frameworks like Wordpress, Google and others, now support the [pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) convention. In this mode, you would "subscribe" to the updates of an RSS flow. The "hub" will call an URL on YOUR site (callback URL) to send you updates : that is a push.

Push or pull, in both cases you still need to write some piece of code to update the RSS list on your site, database or wherever you store/display it.

And, as a side question, it is not necessary to request the whole XML at every pull to see if the content has changed : using a standard that is not linked to RSS, but global to the whole HTTP protocol ([etag and last-modified headers](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/InCFederation/HTTP+Conditional+GET)), you can know if the RSS page was modified after a given date, and grab the whole XML only if modified.

Answer (score 5):

It's a pull. That's why you have to configure your reader how often it should refresh the feed.